# How to additionally deploy to bintray with maven?

Tags: maven, bintray

I have SCM connection in **maven** configuration for deploying artifacts into internal repositories. But on release I want to deploy artifacts to bintray repository **additionally**. I found [gradle-bintray-plugin](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin) for gradle and want to use same approach in maven. Do you now how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple plugin for deploying artifacts to Bintray. Now you can deploy to your internal repositories and Bintray repository on release.
https://github.com/Devexperts/bintray-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1):

This post might help. It explains how to deploy your artifacts to your bintray repository from a maven project:
http://blog.bintray.com/2015/09/17/publishing-your-maven-project-to-bintray/

Comment: Maven can't deploy artifacts to multiple number of repositories. Therefore I wrote "additionally".